# How to get text within <td> within <font> using beautiful soup 4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How should this parse this with beautiful soup 4 when it doesn't recognize `td.font.unwrap()`? 
Should I replace it or something? or unwrap it?

```
<td align="CENTER">
    <font size="+2">横</font>(F
    <font size="+2">橫</font>)
</td>
```

I'd like to just get the string of `横(F橫)` 
What I'm getting right now is: 横(F�)

I'm calling into the td field just fine, but just not able to get the last character...
This is how I'm calling it right now 
`y = cols[1].text`

`cols` is the `<td>` field and this is the second one within the row`<tr>`....

FULL CODE BELOW:

```
    # coding: utf8
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from string import *


conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# # create a table
def createTable():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE characters
                      (rank INTEGER, word TEXT, definition TEXT) 
                   """)


def insertChar(rank,word,definition):
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO characters (rank,word,definition)
                        VALUES (?,?,?)""",(rank,word,definition))


def main():
    createTable()

    # u = unicode("辣", "utf-8")

    # insertChar(1,u,"123123123")

    # content = "\n".join(response.readlines()[1:])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.zein.se/patrick/3000char.html').read())

    # print (html_doc.prettify())   

    tables = soup.blockquote.table

    # print tables



    rows = tables.find_all('tr')[1:]
    result=[]
    for tr in rows:
        # print tr
        cols = tr.find_all('td')
        character = []
        # col = cols.fonts.unwrap()
        # x = int (cols[0].string)
        x = 0
        y = cols[1].text
        # chars = y.find_all('font') 

        z = "11"
        print y
        # y = cols[1].string
        # z = cols[2].string

        # xx = unicode(x, "utf-8")
        # yy = unicode(y , "utf-8")
        # zz = unicode(z , "utf-8")
        insertChar(x,y,z)

    conn.commit() 

main()
```

I appreciate all your help! Thanks

Comment: Please post more code, I get `u'\n\u6a2a(F\n    \u6a6b)\n'` from `td.text` just fine.

Comment: @Pavel Anossov Thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That site claims to be in gb2312, but it's not. This should fix it:

```
url = 'http://www.zein.se/patrick/3000char.html'
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read(), from_encoding='gb18030')
```

or just

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read(), from_encoding='gbk')
```

Your browser figured it out, but BeautifulSoup needs a hint.